# Why is this Z3 query failing

Tags: z3

I am experimenting with Z3, and more specifically with muZ, however some queries fail, and I don't understand why. 
For example this definition of implication

```
(declare-rel imp (Bool Bool))
(declare-var post Bool)

(rule (imp false post))
(rule (=> (imp true post) post))

(query (imp true false) :print-certificate true)
```

gives the error `(error "query failed: Illegal head. The head predicate needs to be uninterpreted and registered (as recursive) (= (:var 0) true)")`

Much larger examples, with many parameters defined with the same structure work as expected. Furthermore by removing the second rule I get the error `ERROR: certificates are not supported for datalog` which makes me suspect that for some reason this problem is being incorrectly interpreted as `datalog`, and the larger problems are being interpreted as `fixedpoint`s.

What makes this query fail?

Answer (score 0):

The format form rules generally assumes that rules have uninterpreted predicates in the head. The second rule has a bound variable in the head.

If you add non-propositional features to the datalog rules, such as arithmetic, 
the fixedpoint engine will seek to dispatch an engine that understands such features. You can control the engine by specifying (set-option :fixedpoint.engine 'engine-name'), where 'engine-name' is datalog/duality/pdr, etc. Support for certificates and answers vary among the engines.